# Approximation of series using integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, approximation

In notes of statistical physics I found the following approximation

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}F\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx \int_{0}^{\infty}F(x)dx+\frac{1}{24}F'(0)$$

for $F$ such that the difference $F(n+1)-F(n)$ is "sufficiently small".

I don't have any idea how to prove it (if it is true) and what in this context means that above difference is "sufficiently small" ?

Comment: look for "Euler MacLaurin formula"

Comment: Without any error bounds, $\approx$ on two fixed quantities has little meaning. The closeness of the approximation is not specified. This is not an asymptotic expansion since both sides are constant. The suggestion of the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula would be useful for asymptotic expansions.

Comment: @robjohn Maybe, it's coming from Statistical Physics and there are other parameters the OP is not showing explicitly. Sometimes, it comes from a high temperature expansion of a partition function or something like that. Usually, the textbooks mention the Euler-MacLaurin formula. The classical example is the rigid rotor and the original formula is something like $\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}\left(2\ell + 1\right)\exp\left(-\,{\ell\left[\ell + 1\right] \over \tau}\right)$ where $\tau$ is $\propto$ the temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's the mid-point rule for integrals

> \begin{align*}
>     \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\, dx &=
>     (b-a)f\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)+
>     \frac{(b-a)^{2}}{24} [f'(b)-f'(a)] \\
>     &\quad \: -
>     \frac{1}{6} \int_{a}^{\frac{a+b}{2}}
>     (t-a)\left( t-\frac{a+b}{2} \right)
>     \left( t+\frac{b-3a}{2} \right) f'''(t) \, dt \\
>     & \quad \: -
>     \frac{1}{6} \int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^{b}
>    (t-b)\left( t-\frac{a+b}{2} \right)
>     \left( t+\frac{a-3b}{2} \right) f'''(t) \, dt \\
>     &=(b-a)f\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)+
>     \frac{(b-a)^{2}}{24} [f'(b)-f'(a)]+O((b-a)^4) \\
>     \int_{0}^{N} F(x) \, dx & \approx
>     \sum_{n=0}^{N} F\left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right)+
>     \frac{F'(N)-F'(0)}{24} \\
> \end{align*}